# Will a 24 volt buzzer work with 19 volt supply lines?

Tags: voltage, piezo-buzzer

I'm fixing up an apartment condo and opened the doorbell buzzer/door unlock wallplate looking to install a new wallplate and button that isn't caked in old paint.  When I slid the housing out, the fragile wires on the buzzer broke off.  I want to replace it with something from this century.  Almost all buzzers I can find are DC but I have found some 24 vac ones that might work.
This is a 3 wire system.  Red and white have 19v and work with the button in my unit to open the door for guests.  There is no transformer in my apartment.  The buzzer worked from the same red wire and used a green wire for neutral.  I tried attaching a cheap door chime to the red and green wires and it works fine, but I would prefer not to have mount an additional item on the wall. http://www.galco.com/buy/Edwards-Signaling/1065-G5 is a likely contender

Comment: Probably, might be a tad quieter though.

Comment: But you can always call them and see... phone number here http://www.edwards-signals.com/index.cfm?pg=18&level=5

Answer (score 0):

I did happen to email them at the same time I asked here.  They said it has a tolerance of +10% to -20% so 19.2% would be the minimum so it will just miss and likely fail to power the coil.
Home Depot sells 16 vac buzzers and I just found an 18 vac buzzer so I will look into these.  Thanks for responding.